# Creating a table with a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to Javascript and I'm trying to populate a table through a loop. The code works fine as long as I only try to populate the table, but when I try to add an IF condition in order to separate headers and data, it does not work any more. I would be curious to understand why it does not work and how can I solve the issue.

Below current broken code:

```
for(i = 0;i < values.length; i ++){
          var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
          tr = document.createElement('tr');

          for (j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
          if (i=0) {
          td = document.createElement('td');
          tr.appendChild(td);
          td.innerHTML = values[i][j];
          }
          } else { 
          td = document.createElement('td');
          tr.appendChild(td);
          td.innerHTML = values[i][j];
          }
}
```

Here the code that works without headers:

```
for(i = 0;i < values.length; i ++){
          var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
          tr = document.createElement('tr');
          for (j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
          td = document.createElement('td');
          tr.appendChild(td);
          td.innerHTML = values[i][j];
          }
           table.appendChild(tr);

}
```

Comment: You forgot to put double == in if statement. Maybe that's the reason? And your brackets look invalid, you put else after a for statement, which is not correct. Check your syntax from here: https://jsfiddle.net/2rd6nax9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put double equal `i==0` not `i=0`

```
if (i==0) {
    td = document.createElement('td');
    tr.appendChild(td);
    td.innerHTML = values[i][j];
}
```

**EDIT**

in your second loup you should close the `if` statement and loop :

```
for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = document.createElement('tr');

  for (j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      td.innerHTML = values[i][j];

    } else {
      td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      td.innerHTML = values[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```